# (Hash-)Map has entry, get delivers null

Tags: java, android, dictionary

I have no idea what is happening here. I have a HashMap with the following keyset of size 4:

```
steps.keySet()
(java.util.HashMap$KeySet)
[INIT_FZLIST, INIT_DATA, INSTALL_DATABASE, PROMPT_GERAETEID]
```

INIT_FZLIST, INIT_DATA, INSTALL_DATABASE and PROMPT_GERAETEID are values of an enum.

Also the entrySet delivers the 4 entries.

```
steps.entrySet()
(java.util.HashMap$EntrySet)
[INIT_FZLIST=de.ansat.terminal.activity.widgets.PendingCheckbox{b50cb4e0 V.E..... ......I. 24,524-456,666},
 INIT_DATA=de.ansat.terminal.activity.widgets.PendingCheckbox{b50c8748 V.E..... ......I. 24,350-456,524},
 INSTALL_DATABASE=de.ansat.terminal.activity.widgets.PendingCheckbox{b508e288 V.E..... ......I. 24,68-456,209},
 PROMPT_GERAETEID=de.ansat.terminal.activity.widgets.PendingCheckbox{b50c59b0 V.E..... ......I. 24,209-456,350}]
```

but if I do this:

```
steps.get(INSTALL_DATABASE)
 null
```

the map returns null and of cause I get a nullpointerexception if I try to work with the resulting object.

This is running in an Android activity.
I'm using Android 4.2.2 on API Level 17

[Edit]

```
private Map<InstallSteps, PendingCheckbox> steps = new HashMap<InstallSteps, PendingCheckbox>();
```

is a field of my activity class.

I have several AsyncTasks working on that map, as it represents the progress of an installation process.

PendingCheckbox is a View extending LinearLayout.

[Edit2]
steps is filled in onCreate(..) this way:

```
    PendingCheckbox installDb = new PendingCheckbox(InstallActivity.this);
    installDb.setText(INSTALL_DATABASE);
    installDb.setChecked(false);
    installDb.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    root.addView(installDb);
    steps.put(InstallSteps.INSTALL_DATABASE, installDb);
```

Has anyone an idea what might cause this behaviour? I'm completly stuck.
Any tip would be appreciated!

Comment: what is INSTALL_DATABASE, enum ? String? variable?

Comment: What type is the 'INSTALL_DATABASE'?

Comment: sorry: 
private enum InstallSteps {
  INSTALL_DATABASE,
  PROMPT_GERAETEID,
  INIT_DATA,
  INIT_FZLIST,
 }

Comment: This kind of behavior is likely to occur when `hashcode()` / `equals()` methods are not consistent between two calls on the same object. Can you please post the full Enum class content ?

Comment: no, I have not. Should I?

Comment: the above is the full enum content - I will override equals and come back...

Comment: equals is final in enums...

Comment: I implemented hashcode() / equals() in PendingCheckbox with no change - same behaviour.

Comment: I suspect the `HashMap` got modified before you called `get()`

Comment: Ok, I try to synchronize it...

Comment: I removed the map now and use the PendingCheckboxes directly. Still confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [EnumMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) instead of `HashMap`.

> A specialized Map implementation for use with enum type keys. All of the keys in an enum map must come from a single enum type that is specified, explicitly or implicitly, when the map is created.

As far as your code is concerned , remember:

1. The `hashCode` of the Objects in map should not change once added to map. A good implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()` is required.
2. Check if you actually `put(key,value)` an object with that `key` before `get(key)`ing its value.

Comment: 1) I used eclipses equals genarator. The fields of PendingCheckbox are Android Views and another enum value. So it should be correct.
2) as one can see the steps.entrySet() shows the key is included in the map.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe steps is altered before the get, or the puts occur later, or you have two declarations of steps.

Comment: The methods hashCode() and equals(...) are final in Enum<E extends Enum<E>>. They just cannot be overridden. And it even doesn't make sense, as the values of an enum are singletons.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose thanks; removed reservation w.r.t. hashCode (it would be hard to unintentionally make a non-functioning hashCode).